# Keeping aspect ratio in C (ncurses)

Tags: c, ncurses

I need to make a game using ncurses in C.
The game needs to be 80(char)x24(char).
I need an status bar on the bottom (5 char) so I hardcoded it.

I made this loop to keep things centralized, but I can't figure out how to keep the aspect ratio when the terminal screen is resized.

Is there any way to do it using ncurses?

I need the screen to always stay at least 80x24, perhaps using fullscreen mode always, I don't really need screen resizing.

Here's the loop to keep things in their places (status bar poorly hardcoded, the aspect ratio is a mess)

```
/* LOOP TO CENTRALIZE FOR ANY RESIZING */
  while (1){
    getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);
    clear();
    mvprintw(yMax/24, xMax/80, "BEG");
    mvprintw(yMax/2, xMax/2, "CENTER %d %d", yMax, xMax);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1)); /* bottom status bar (5 lines) */
    int i, j;
    for ( j=(yMax-5) ; j <= yMax ; j++){

      for ( i=0 ; i <= xMax ; i++ ){
        mvprintw(j, i, " ");
      }

    }
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    refresh();
  }
```

Comment: What is the ratio of 80 over 24? You need to make sure the resized ration is the same.

Comment: I made a window before this loop:

      WINDOW * win = newwin(24, 80, 0, 0);

      getyx(stdscr, y, x);
      getbegyx(win, yBeg, xBeg);

Comment: I'm trying to fix the aspect ratio for hours, I really don't know what to do anymore

Comment: The ratio of 80 over 24 (the aspect ratio you want to keep) is `3.3333`. So the width should always be `3.3333` times larger than the height.

Comment: Ok! But how can I keep it this way? Should I use a window with a fixed size instead of stdscr and keep it always centralized?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, That assumes 80x24 is square, and it might not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your program reads input, e.g., calls `getch`, ncurses will continue using the original screen-size (and look confused).  When you call `getch` after ncurses receives a `SIGWINCH`, it returns `KEY_RESIZE`, and at that point ncurses updates its screen-size.